# Bounty system and automatic awards

Tags: support, bounties

Can someone please explain the bounty system?

I answered a question that featured a 50 rep bounty that no one else answered and I received nothing,

The other day [I answered a question first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428180/message-security-with-mutual-certificates-for-android-ios/52539255#52539255) that featured a 500 rep bounty and got 3 upvotes. Before the bounty ended someone posted another answer and also got 3 upvotes. He got 250 points when the bounty ended but I didn't.

Why is that? and if there is no automatic split system that provides half of the bounty isn't that going to make some people to abuse it?

Comment: What new system are you talking about? Unless I'm mistaken, answering a bountied question doesn't necessarily mean you'll get said bounty. In the first case, since you got nothing, I reckon whoever set up the bounty simply did not want to award it to your answer. But what intrigues me is this "new bounty system" you're talking about?

Comment: i remember i was told once if no one answered a 50% of the bounty is awarded automatically

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at [the main post on bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/398063), see if the part on automatic awarding answers your question. If not, maybe edit it to address how it doesn't?

Comment: We probably need links to the answers so we can check the context.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428180/message-security-with-mutual-certificates-for-android-ios/52539255#52539255 , this one for instance i am the older answer and we both have the same score

Comment: like i just need an explanation of that, how it really worked out on this case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[That question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428180/message-security-with-mutual-certificates-for-android-ios) [has had two bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52428180/timeline).

The first bounty started on September 24th and finished on October 2nd. [Your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52539255/timeline) gained its 3 upvotes on October 10th i.e. after the bounty ended and so was not eligible for that bounty's auto award as it did not meet the scoring criteria at that point. Per the [bounty privileges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties):

> If you do not award the bounty within 24 hours of the bounty period ending, half the bounty value will be automatically awarded to the top voted answer posted after the bounty start, provided it has a score of at least 2. If no new answer matches this requirement, no reputation will be awarded at all, and the reputation used on the bounty will be lost forever.

I.e. it would have had to have had a score of at least 2 on October 2nd.

On October 3rd another bounty was added to the question but your answer already existed by that point so it was not eligible for an auto award because of that no matter what it scored.

Either bounty could have been manually awarded in its entirety to your answer but neither was.